# Как создать фильтр продуктов Spring boot(Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc

Хочу создать фильтр для магазина как на этом сайте https://voyager3md.com/ Идея такая, чтобы можно было например поставить галочку на (цена < 1000) и например продукция "Самсунг" и, что бы он выводил на экран продукты которые подходят под это условие, но проблема в том что таких условий может быть много

Единственное пока до чего я додумался это

```
public interface itemRepo extends CrudRepository<ItemModel,Long> {

    LinkedList<ItemModel>findByTypeOrPriceOrSale(String type,int price,boolean sale);
}
```

Но такой способ не подходит так как даже если я сделаю большой метод, некоторые поля останутся null, и выводится ничего не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface itemRepo extends CrudRepository<ItemModel,Long> {

    @Query("select * from youTable where type == :type and price < :price")
    LinkedList<ItemModel>findByTypeOrPriceOrSale(@Param("type") String type,@Param("price") int price,boolean sale);
}
```

Пишите свой запрос с требуемыми параметрами.

Comment: А как динамическая сортировка будет выглядеть, т.е сортировка(order) по двум/трем/четырем аттрибутам?

Comment: А в чем проблема добавить любое количество параметров в стринг и делать order by? Только для этого проще использовать EntityManager или JdbcTemplate, смотря что вам больше подходит.